# Why is fish redirection not working as expected

Tags: fish

When I try to redirect fish shell output to a file, the *command* gets put in the file, not the command output. why? This works as expected in bash, zsh etc.

example:

```
$  fish --version
fish, version 3.2.0

$ rm -f /tmp/foo
$ echo bar > /tmp/foo
$ cat /tmp/foo
echo bar

# expected output:
bar

# It's not related to the echo command. e.g:
$ ls -l > /tmp/foo
$ cat /tmp/foo
ls -l
```

Comment: What's your `fish --version`?

Comment: good point - I updated the question with the version

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce on either 3.1.2, 3.2.0, or 3.2.1 (I get the expected result).  But I'm thinking it may be related to [this](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7836) for you.  Based on that, other things to consider -- What's your terminal?  Anything special in the prompt?  Thanks for adding the info on `ls -l` -- That answers my next question.  I was going to ask about `/bin/echo`, but I now assume it has the same problem.

Comment: It is something in my config. If I move `~/.config/fish` aside the issue goes away. But I don't actually have much config in `~/.config/fish`, so I wonder what it can be. I have tried different terminals, so not related to that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been caused by a bug in `fishgretel/fasd`

See
https://github.com/fishgretel/fasd/commit/98fb3873aae9adcca2ffc4b4b3958e45d74cb894